# The independent random variable X and Y have standard deviation 4 and 7 respectively. calculate the standard deviation of: 2X+3Y

Tags: probability, statistics

For this question,in probability and statistics, the answer is 22.5 however I don't know how to get to it. I tried variance=2(4)^2+3(7)^2= 179 and to get standard deviation rooted 179 and got 13.37 which is wrong. Any tips or help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $V(X)$ the variance of $X$, then
$$V(2X + 3Y)=2^{2}V(X)+3^{2}V(Y)$$
assuming $X$ and $Y$ to be independent random variables. Now, if the standard deviation of $X$ is $4$ then $V(X)=4^{2}$, and we are over.

Comment: it goes without saying that once you take the suare root of such variance you will find your result.

Comment: i did 2^2(4)+3^2(7) and got 79 i rooted it it became 8.9 which is wrong i dont know what to do.

Comment: You better calculate as @DavideTrono suggested: $2^2\cdot16+3^2\cdot49$ for the variance of $2X+3Y$.  Now take the square root.

Comment: YESSSSS its correct so i have to make 4 and 7 to the power of 2 too but why?

Comment: By definition: the variance is the square of the standard deviation ...